# wpa_supplicant not working properly on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wpa-supplicant, wpa

```
sudo iw wlp2s0 link                                                             
[sudo] password for aadesh: 
Connected to f0:3e:90:38:76:d8 (on wlp2s0)
    SSID: RAM
    freq: 2472
    RX: 4191824 bytes (17917 packets)
    TX: 196641 bytes (1161 packets)
    signal: -48 dBm
    tx bitrate: 72.2 MBit/s MCS 7 short GI

    bss flags:  short-preamble short-slot-time
    dtim period:    1
    beacon int: 100
```

The above command shows connected but I'm not able to access any website other than my college's dc++ network.

Here's my wpa_supplicant.conf file :

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
  ssid="RAM"
  scan_ssid=1
  key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
  identity="id"
  password="psk"
  eap=PEAP
  phase1="peaplabel=0"
  phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

Comment: wpa_supplicant is working properly if you are connected.  If you can't acess any other website than the one form your university it is due to the netwrok configuration. Contatct your IT.

Comment: The wifi works perfectly fine on my phone.

Comment: wpa_supplicant doesn't seems to be the issue here... start by the baeginning. Check your IP, ping your gateway , ping an external website such as 9.9.9.9, use `traceroute`.